# await some functions and continue to run some code while waiting for Task.WhenAll?

Tags: c#, async-await, task

There are the following functions.

```
async Task<int> T1() { Console.WriteLine("T1"); return await Task.FromResult(1); }
async Task<string> T2() { Console.WriteLine("T2"); return await Task.FromResult("T2"); }
async Task<char> T3() { await Task.Delay(2000); Console.WriteLine("T3"); return await Task.FromResult('A'); }
async Task<string> T4() { Console.WriteLine("T4"); return await Task.FromResult("T4"); }

// U1, U2, U3, and U4 need to be run right after T1, T2, T3, and T4 respectively
void U1() { System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); Console.WriteLine($"After T1"); }
void U2() { System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000); Console.WriteLine($"After T2"); }
void U3() { System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); Console.WriteLine($"After T3"); }
void U4() { System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); Console.WriteLine($"After T4"); }

// TAll() needs to be run as soon as T1, T2, T3, and T4 finished.
void TAll() { Console.WriteLine("To be run after T1, T2, T3, T4"); }

// All() runs after all functions are done.
void All() { Console.WriteLine("To be run after U1, U2, U3, U4"); }
```

However, the following calls

```
var t1 = T1().ContinueWith(_ => U1());
var t2 = T2().ContinueWith(_ => U2());
var t3 = T3().ContinueWith(_ => U3());
var t4 = T4().ContinueWith(_ => U4());
await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2, t3, t4);
TAll();

All();
```

returns

```
T1
T2
T4
After T1
After T4
T3
After T3
After T2
To be run after T1, T2, T3, T4
To be run after U1, U2, U3, U4
```

The expected output order is

```
T1
T2
T4
After T1
After T4
T3
To be run after T1, T2, T3, T4
After T3
After T2
To be run after U1, U2, U3, U4
```

Comment: You are actually waiting for all continuations to finish not their target tasks...

Comment: If I wait all on T#, the U# will not be called right after T functions are done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should [use `async` and `await` rather than `ContinueWith`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html). In your case, adding new `async` methods will simplify the code:

```
var t1 = T1();
var u1 = InvokeU1(t1);
var t2 = T2();
var u2 = InvokeU2(t2);
var t3 = T3();
var u3 = InvokeU3(t3);
var t4 = T4();
var u4 = InvokeU4(t4);

await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2, t3, t4);
TAll();

await Task.WhenAll(u1, u2, u3, u4);
All();

async Task InvokeU1(Task task) { await task; U1(); }
async Task InvokeU2(Task task) { await task; U2(); }
async Task InvokeU3(Task task) { await task; U3(); }
async Task InvokeU4(Task task) { await task; U4(); }
```

Answer (score 3):

The continuation of the task is actually task. In your example your are awaiting on the continuations so *"To be run after..."* will be logged when all target tasks and all their continuations are done.

Consider this:

```
//target tasks
var t1 = T1();
var t2 = T2();
var t3 = T3();
var t4 = T4();

//continuations
var c1 = t1.ContinueWith(_ => U1());
var c2 = t2.ContinueWith(_ => U2());
var c3 = t3.ContinueWith(_ => U3());
var c4 = t4.ContinueWith(_ => U4());

await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2, t3, t4);
TAll();

await Task.WhenAll(c1, c2, c3, c4);
All();
```

The output will be in line with what you expect.

**Update**

Stephen added a good tip about `ContinueWith` and I encourage you to use it. However regardless how dangerous `ContinueWith` is here I tried to explain the problem conceptually.

Comment: Great. Is there other ways to do it without using continuewith?

Comment: @ca9163d9: [You should not use `ContinueWith` in real-world code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html). Use an `async` method instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2, t3, t4);` this ensures T1(),T2(),T3(),T4() and its associated U1(),U2(),U3(),U4() (order depends upon the thread sleep or task.deley you have mentioned in each of those) to complete before it goes on to execute TALL() and ALL() in the sequence. Hence below two statement is the last to print

```
To be run after T1, T2, T3, T4
To be run after U1, U2, U3, U4
```